# How do I allow programs that generate "high" or "severe" alerts in MS Security Essentials?

Tags: ms-security-essentials

Microsoft Security Essentials seems to allow only quarantine or delete actions for program that it deems to have "high" or "severe" risk.

However, it also assigns these levels to what it considers to be "hacking tools".

Is there a way to override this nanny behaviour and force programs on the allowed list?

Here's a screenshot showing the lack of an "Allow" option in the drop-down list:

[image]

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but I found that if you quarantine it and then restore straight away, the file becomes unblocked. Having said that, this seems to suggest MSE is no better in terms of UI than all the other products...

Comment: Short answer: You don’t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstalling the program solved the issue.

Comment: Which program? I tried re-installing MSE, but that hasn't changed anything.

Comment: Uninstalling completely then reinstalling worked for me.  Don't really know what the problem was.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this issue, but after changing each default action to "recomended action" (also made sure that the box to auto perform default actions was unchecked).

STILL no "allow".  BUT, if you CHECK THE BOX next to the item in quarantine, THEN you can allow it.

I was very frustrated until I checked the box!

Answer (score 1):

- When Security Essentials
  displays the notification, click the
  Show details link.
- In the Potential
  threat details dialog box, select the
  program, click the down arrow in the
  Recommendation column, and then click
  Allow.
- Click Apply actions. If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or confirm the action.

EDIT:

If no "Allow" option is available. Submit your file to Microsoft:  Open MSE.  To the right of MSE is a down pointer.  CLick on that and select submit malicious sample, and fill in the form with the appropriate information.

[SOURCE](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/protect_scanning/cant-allow-severe-risk/2ee574bb-c33a-41cf-962b-ac2727c7d63c)

Comment: I have found no way to undo this allow action, I have done this for a file or two and can find no way to reverse this decision, it does not put it in the allow list either.

Comment: I would not be asking this question if "Allow" was on the list for such events

Comment: @Alex O the allow option should be in the drop down box which in the screenshot displays "Quarantine"

Comment: Unfortunately, "Quarantine" is the only option in that dropdown.

Comment: If no "Allow" option is available. Submit your file to Microsoft: Open MSE. To the right of MSE is a down pointer. CLick on that and select submit malicious sample, and fill in the form with the appropriate information.

Comment: -1: does not answer the question

Answer (score 1):

If you change the default action of severe alert level to "Recommended action" it will allow you to allow the "threat".

Comment: This doesn't work if MSE has already detected a "threat". It might work on new items, not sure yet.